# What kind of privatekey is this?

Tags: ethereum, cryptocurrency

```
+LpXP5z4wSFhwaq60lgWLQ5sF9MMIaFiovqmmEJvlLHWCneNWjWyTw/JD4cxpPU/rCy/xHYRmZNUH2tUziXRIatftRIEEYeQ1PQcihUcars=
```

It is supposed to be a eth privatekey?
i have never seen any format like this.
Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: Ethereum private key is 256bits (mostly represented as 64 hex characters). This looks like some `base<N>` encoding, possibly used by a wallet software. Some wallets use master password to encrypt the private keys, and then encode this encrypted binary  using `base<N>` so that they are able to store it in a text file.

Comment: That's strange coze base<N> doesnt use passwords for encoding

Comment: The private key is first encoded using some symmetric algo with password - to some binary... And then this binary is encoded using base<N>... But again, this is what some wallets do, but I'm not sure whether it's really the case here. It just seems like base<N>, so that was my wild guess based on the information that this is supposed to be a private key.

Comment: Yes it is, and it makes some sense now even thou i figured it must be base64 because of the characters (+,/) that are not in any lower base encoding....it's just that the base64 result is gibberish. Assuming it was first encrypted in some other way and then userd base64 i was thinking the result should be another form of string that is encrypted, or is my thinking wrong?

Comment: If you use base64 to encode a **binary**, then it decodes back to binary - and the string representation of this result is going to be gibberish.